# Unable to receive '\' character in post WCF request .NET C#

Tags: c#, wcf

```
{ "string001Value":"LITTELFUSE \\/ 772291851034","string002Value":"772291851034","string003Value":"","string004Value":""... }
```

When sending a Json object the WCF service receives it without the backslash '', the `string001Value` property receives the value of "`LITTELFUSE / 772291851034`".

How can I receive this type of characters in the service so that the value is "`LITTELFUSE \ / 772291851034`"?

this is the WebInvoke Method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           UriTemplate = "warehouse_shipping_advice")]
_ResponseDetail WarehouseShippingAdvice(_WarehouseShipping newWarehouseShipping);
```

Comment: What is your `WebInvoke` definitions? for example, the following works for me: `[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`.

Comment: i have this info @OfirD                   
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "warehouse_shipping_advice")]
_ResponseDetail WarehouseShippingAdvice(_WarehouseShipping newWarehouseShipping);

Comment: This is identical to mine. What is your client code? please add it to your question (and at the same time, add your `WebInvoke` definitions from your comment to the question).

Comment: i edited the question @OfirD, is it ok?

Comment: It's better, but the client code is still missing. you need to add the code that actually does the http post request with that json, calling `WarehouseShippingAdvice`.

Comment: ooh i got it, i'm using a postman platform  sending the body like JSON content                             
--header 'Auth: value' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-StockAndTrace-Signature: value' \

is it necessary the json content?

Comment: Yes, it's important to mention that in the question. Now that you have Ding Peng's answer, take a look at it, because - as I also said - it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I did a test but did not find the problem, here is my demo:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "warehouse_shipping_advice")]
        void WarehouseShippingAdvice(_WarehouseShipping newWarehouseShipping);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class _WarehouseShipping
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string string001Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void WarehouseShippingAdvice(_WarehouseShipping newWarehouseShipping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newWarehouseShipping.string001Value);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Step 1: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");

            // Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);

            try
            {
                // Step 3: Add a service endpoint.
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WebHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { HelpEnabled=true});

                // Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Step 5: Start the service.
                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

                // Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my service. I enabled the help document in the service.

[image]

According to the help document, we can request the service correctly.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: can you try using online one \/ and not \\/ please

Comment: I update my reply. In c#, "\\" represents a backslash, for more information about Escape Sequences, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.